# Correct font in table of contents for list of figures using classicthesis

Tags: table-of-contents, classicthesis

I'm using classicthesis for my master thesis and have included a list of figures using:

```
\listoffigures
```

The list of figures appears in the wrong font in the toc.

So when I simply do:

```
\documentclass[dottedtoc, hidelinks, headinclude, footinclude=true, listof=totoc, bibliography=totoc]{scrbook}
\usepackage[pdfspacing, linedheaders]{classicthesis}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[babel, style=english]{csquotes}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First Section}
This is a funky chapter...

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\end{document}
```

This produces the following output:
[image: TOC]

The entry for LOF in the TOC is neither in capital letters nor is it the correct font which is used for the section heading.

Is there a way to fix that?

Thank you!

Roman

Comment: Something like this is neither defined by `classicthesis` nor any other class/package. This is a local thing just for `biblatex`. It cannot work and it isn't supposed to.

Comment: Okay, but how can I then include the lof in the correct font?

Comment: What is the correct font? Normally, classicthesis sets up stuff like it is supposed to do. Please provide a minimal working example.

Comment: I added a working example which does not require the defbibheading command but still shows the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can patch the macro in `tocbasic.sty`:

```
\documentclass[
  dottedtoc, 
  hidelinks,
  headinclude,
  footinclude=true,
  listof=totoc,
  bibliography=totoc
]{scrbook}
\usepackage[pdfspacing, linedheaders]{classicthesis}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[babel, style=english]{csquotes}
\usepackage{regexpatch}

\makeatletter
\def\toc@spacedlowsmallcaps#1{%
  \texorpdfstring{\noexpand\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}{#1}%
}
\xpatchcmd{\tocbasic@listhead}
  {\addxcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{##1}}
  {\addxcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\toc@spacedlowsmallcaps{##1}}}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{First Section}
This is a funky chapter...

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures

\end{document}
```

[image]